# ASP.NET MVC validating model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am having some difficulties in validation of form.

Since I want to populate combobox from database (another table, I'm using viewbags to do this), is there a way to use ComboBoxFor in this case so I could use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and jquery.validate.js?

View:

```
@model MyProject.OpenAccess.Document
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDocument", "Create", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <label>Select file:</label><br />
  <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
  <label>Filetype</label><br />
  @Html.DropDownList("fileType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListFiletypes, "-Filetypes", new { @class = "filetype-cb" }) <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file, string fileType)
{
  if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
  {
    Document doc = new Document()
    {
      Filetype = fileType
    }
    if (this.TryValidateModel(doc))
    {
      this.dbContext.Add(doc);
      this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
      id = doc.ID;
      //save document using document ID
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my current implementation of this:

**Layout.cshtml**

Remember to add:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**View**

```
@model MyProject.OpenAccess.Document
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDocument", "Create", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label>Select file:</label><br />
    <input type="file" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file!" name="file" /><br />
    <label>Filetype</label><br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FileType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListFiletypes, "", new { @class = "filetype-cb" })
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult CreateDocument()
{
    ViewBag.ListFiletypes = new SelectList(this.dbContext.ListFiletypes.ToList(), "FileType", "FileType");
    //Populate dropdownlist from database
}

[HttpPost]

 public ActionResult CreateDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file, Document doc)
 {
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        if (this.TryValidateModel(doc))
        {
            this.dbContext.Add(doc);
            this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
            id = doc.ID;
            //save document using document ID
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public partial class Document
{
    private int _iD;
    public virtual int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._iD;
        }
        set
        {
            this._iD = value;
        }
    }

    private string _fileType;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    public virtual string FileType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._fileType;
        }
        set
        {
            this._fileType = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there good reasons to use Viewmodel over Viewbag to populate DropDownListFors (found this from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC)?

Only problem with this implementation is that I can't validate file on client-side (so user couldn't post empty file).

EDIT: Got this working by just adding:

```
  <input type="file" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file!" name="file" />
```

Comment: If you don't have a model and add validation attributes to the properties of the model, then you wont get validation out of the box. Since you declare `@model Document` in the view, then `Document` needs to have a property `fileType`, or use a view model to display and edit what you want

Comment: Are you looking for @Html.DropDownListFor ? You can use this with the model's property and then validate it with a Data Annotation.

Comment: @Stephen, I have validation attributes assigned to model attributes.

Comment: @Muthu, Yes, I meant DropDownListFor, but I got a problem:
How can I populate DropDownListFor from Viewbag?

Comment: You need to post your model. If you have a property named `fileType` there there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have 3 different parts, which build a proper implementation of your scenario.

### The ViewModel:

In a proper implementation, you got for every view its own Viewmodel. In your case that would be something like this:

```
public class CreateDocumentViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> filetypes { get; set; }
    // Maybe some more attributes you need in the view?
}
```

**Note**: here you can use the DataAnnotations you want.

### The View:

The view contains the actual data in the dropdown.

```
@model CreateDocumentViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDocument", "Create", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     <label>Select file:</label><br />
     <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
     <label>Filetype</label><br />
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.filetypes, model.filetypes, "-Filetypes", new { @class = "filetype-cb" })
     <br />
     <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
}
```

### The controller:

The controller you need, has 2 actions. A GET- and a POST-action.

```
[HttpGet]       
public ActionResult CreateDocument()
{
    CreateDocumentViewModel model = new CreateDocumentViewModel();
    model.filetypes = FillFileTypesFromDB; // Here you fill the data for the dropdown!
    return View(model);    
}
```

Finally you need the POST-action which saves back to your db.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file, string fileType)
{
  if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
  {
    Document doc = new Document()
    {
      Filetype = fileType
    }
    if (this.TryValidateModel(doc))
    {
      this.dbContext.Add(doc);
      this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
      id = doc.ID;
      //save document using document ID
    }
  }
}
```

I hope I fully understood your problem and it helps solving it.

Comment: Thanks for your clear example. So I should include my model (MyProject.OpenAccess.Document) and those dropdownlists in same viewmodel? In your example it seems you're validating filetypes collection (DropDownList data) and not validating when you're posting the form back, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes that's the idea. The data annotations in the viewmodel are validated as soon as you post the form. For example if you had a viewmodel and a property "password" inside decorated with "required", you can't post your form until you fill out the password field in your view.